# Why does using a different type of session affect whether or not the variables are initialized in tensorflow?

Tags: python, session, tensorflow

I am trying to run a classifier on the MNIST dataset.  I know that I need to initialize a session in order to do this correctly.

But, the other thing I want to do is print out the values when I'm running the training iterations on the neural network.

so, I try to print out the line `print(sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}))` to print out the values of these variables.  the following code is runnable if you have `tensorflow` installed:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

data_dir='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data'

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(data_dir, one_hot=True)

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy =    tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

# sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# Train
for k in range(1000):
    # print loss function at each iteration 
    if k%100 == 0 and k!=0:
        print(sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}))
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

I have two related problems about this. The problem is when I try to run this by initializing my session using `sess = tf.Session()` I get a `FailedPredictionError`:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_14
     [[Node: Variable_14/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_14"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_14)]]
```

Then, I try to do this using instead of `Session()` I use `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` (which you can see is the line above it).  When I do that, it works, but it is printing `None` instead of the actual value of the loss function.

My two questions are:

- Why does the type of `Session` I am using affect whether or not the variable is initialized?
- Why is the line for printing `print(sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})` print `None` instead of the actual value of the loss function at that training step?  I want to observe the loss function changing across iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to initialize variables in a session like the following:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # or tf.global_variables_initializer().run(sess = sess)

#or

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

You might wonder what is the difference.

Because when you use `tf.InteractiveSession()` to create a session, this `InteractiveSession` installs itself as the default session on construction. That means you can directly call `operation.run()` to run this operation with this session.

But If you are using `tf.Session()`, you need to explicitly point out which session to use when run a operation. So If you use `tf.Session()`, the code in your question is broken as the global variables initializer is not bound with your session. This is your first question.

---

The second question is because you are not understand well how tensorflow works. The results of `sess.run()` just return what the operations return. And operation `.minimize()` won't return what you expect. If you want to get the loss, the code should like the following:

```
if k%100 == 0 and k!=0:
    print(sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}))
```

**Attention**, because I can't test your code, so there may be some mistakes, comment me if you want.

Comment: My reputation will not let me vote yet, but thank you.

Comment: I think I did?  sorry...i'm newto this